# create a popup from a block

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, popup

I created a question a few weeks ago (https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64925/popup-review-form) about how to display a popup from an html block and not from a url and it has been deleted because it is too "broad". I personally find it clear, but nevermind.

I took time today to dig further and find a solution, and I think it could help people, that's why I create this thread with the solution.

Here's the original question (to allow search result to find this post):

> I have a problem which seems really simple to resolve I think, but I'm
>   kind of stuck on it.
>
> I'm trying to display the "write your own review" form inside a popup
>   without using external libraries like fancybox etc. This way customers
>   will see the existing review list on the product page, and they'll be
>   able to access the form to add a review by cliking on a link ('write a
>   review') which display the form in a popup.
>
> I looked for the js function popWin(), but I need to pass a URL in it
>   and I don't have any, as my block review form is added through
>   $this->getChildHtml('review_form').
>
> I could create a hidden div and make it appear through js and CSS, but
>   I really would like to keep using Magento's existing tools and keeping
>   the same layout as the other popups.
>
> Do you have an idea to put that block inside a popup ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the solution given below display a ask a question form and not the review form as detailed in the question, but it is the exact same process.

app/design/frontend/your_theme(default/default)/layout/Catalog.xml:

> Add this in the head reference tags

```
 <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/window.js</script></action>
 <action method="addCss">
     <stylesheet>lib/prototype/windows/themes/magento.css</stylesheet>
 </action>
```

app/design/frontend/your_theme(default/default)/template/Catalog/Product/View.phtml:

```
<div id="product_info_udqa" style="display:none;"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('info_udqa') ?></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("product_info_udqa_link").addEventListener("click", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        document.getElementById("product_info_udqa").setAttribute("style", "display:block");

        var win = new Window({title: "Ask a Question", className: "magento", zIndex:3000, destroyOnClose: true, recenterAuto:false, resizable: false, width:450, height:473, minimizable: false, maximizable: false, draggable: false});
        win.setContent("product_info_udqa", true, false);
        win.showCenter(true);

        win.setCloseCallback(function(){
            document.getElementById("product_info_udqa").setAttribute("style", "display:none");
            return true;
        });
    });
</script>
```